# Running wine on mac to get Windows drivers working

Tags: macos, drivers, wine, kext

If the required kexts for macOS are not available and macOS does not support my device natively, can I still use devices like modem, soundbox, etc on macOS by installing wine and then installing all the required Windows based drivers in the form of .exe files?

Does this solution have limitations or is it a perfect solution? Can this solution be applied to Linux as well as macOS?

Comment: Drivers are not exe files; they do not run on top of the OS they run beneath it. Have you tried just plugging any of these devices in & seeing what happens? Most drivers for generic equipment is built directly into macOS itself - that's often why there's no installer for them on Mac.

Comment: Yes I have but no luck and more precisely I am taking about these exe files which contain drives and without them even windows cannot play sounds for example https://realtek-download.com/download-hd/amp/

Comment: Then the exe will be an installer, not even a driver - even less use. In short, no, this will not work. Without specifics there's nothing more anyone can say.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong terms  but are there any other ways I can do that .I didn't even find any kexts.

Comment: I was trying to play sounds through Intex subwoofers on Mac and the link which I provided only helped me on Windows

Comment: You are really not being clear at all. I'm struggling to see how any speaker would require drivers of any sort to play audio through them. Speakers have been plug & play since before we had computers - so please be clear about why you think a speaker won't be recognised without special drivers. Are you trying to persuade a stereo output to be 5.1, or what…?

Comment: This is exactly same subwoofer that I have https://www.amazon.in/Intex-2600-Computer-Multimedia-Speaker/dp/B00C6WHJEA

Comment: Sorry my bad I cam not that familiar with those terms and by the way thanks for helping

Comment: So it's not drivers you need at all, it's an audio interface. No Mac comes with a Realtek 7.1 audio output, so you need to get something that can take USB & convert it. You then plug the speakers into that. No drivers required. Pick the cheapest one of these that is an external 'box' rather than looks like a flash stick.

Comment: Here's a link back to amazon India - https://www.amazon.in/s?k=5.1+usb+sound&i=computers&ref=nb_sb_noss_2 Basically, don't get one with only mic & headphones sockets, get one with 'real' 5.1, not 'virtual'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

WINE is a userspace system call translation layer, which receives Windows-type calls and translates them into native OS-type calls, and translates replies back. That is all interface it provides. There is no interface for drivers, so you can't use it to adapt Windows drivers to other OS; the only part of drivers that could benefit from WINE is their userspace part.

There are projects which do allow use of Windows drivers in other OS, like, for example, ndiswrapper. These convert OS native-type driver requests into Windows-type requests, then forward them to Windows driver, and translate replies back. Note the direction of translation is "reversed" here compared to that of WINE.